# DocuSign oauth process and charging for envelope request

Tags: docusignapi

I am a developer who is creating DocuSign integration. I want to authenticate other production account using this integration. I have worked with other third party integration(like salesforce, mailchimp, etc.), usually it works fine for other integrations. I just want to confirm that it is the same case here in docusign.

About pricing, If I push my integration to production and authenticate other DocuSign account (if possible) using that integration, then when ever other production account uses this integration to send envelope requests for signing then who will get charged for it? my account or authenticated user's account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can authenticate other DocuSign users' accounts and can send envelopes for signature on behalf of them, DocuSign call this type of Integration a Partner App Integration, where you application will be a Partner App and your users will authenticate your App to call DocuSign API on their behalf. You can check [Service Integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) of how to accomplish this, you need to check User Consent section in your scenario. Now answer to your 2nd qs, Authenticate User's account will be charged for any envelope sent from the authenticated User's account.